# Sliding Navigation Bar with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigationbar

I was trying to create a horizontal navigation bar for a website. Now I need to provide a sliding effect as follows

the navigation menu has 5 links , and the 5th link is a right arrow image. while clicking on this 5th link (right arrow) all other 4 links should be collapsed into this 5th menu and the right arrow should be replaced with a left arrow (now only one link which is the left arrow, and while clicking on this link the previous menu should be enabled)

How can I achieve this?

[edit]
Here is the screen shot of the navbar
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFMXb.png
[/edit]

Comment: can you please give us an image and the code you already have thankyou

Comment: see the screenshot , while clicking on the right arrow , the other 5 tabs should slid right and disappear. and the right arrow should be replaced by a left arrow!! how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok you can try this - http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/11/30/beautiful-slide-out-navigation-a-css-and-jquery-tutorial/

and the demo is here - http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FixedNavigationTutorial/

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the links for reference.